# How to show error message if field left blank or default value in jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to show error message if any of the field left blank or default value in jquery validate. My following code work when field left blank. But it don't work if i left field in default value. Please, any one can help me solving this problem. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Validation Plugin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
    required: function() {return ($("#name").val()== "Name" || $("#name").val()== "");}
            },
            password: {
                required: function() {return ($("#password").val()== "Password" || $("#password").val()== "");}
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Name required"
                            },
            password: {
                required: "Password required"
            }
        }

    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#myform input.error {
border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="Password"  id="password"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should typically for this use placeholder HTML5 attribute:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"  id="password"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For older browsers which don't support this attribute, use a polyfill as this one: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following..

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules:
    {
        name: { required: true },
        password: { required: true }

    }
});
```

});